# Facebook API - what kind of authentication is needed now to query a page's tagged posts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

I want to be able to get the `tagged` posts for a page (e.g. harvard). what kind of authentication do i need to have (`access_token`) or do in order to be able to get those posts? they are publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

You answer lies in the link you posted (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

In the connections section, it says "any valid access_token or user access_token":

> **tagged**
>
> The photos, videos, and posts in which the Page has been tagged.
>
> any valid access_token or user access_token
>
> a heterogeneous array of Photo, Video or Post objects.

So if this is incorrect, you can scroll to the bottom of the link and click the Report Bug link to report an error in the documentation.